# Creating a UI Designer

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, silverlight, user-interface

I'd like to create a UI designer using Silverlight, WPF, or WinForms for a custom system. What's the best way to go around this?

What namespaces, sdks, etc should I be aware of?

Comment: This question is *extremely* broad. Is there any way you can narrow it down? There are tons of namespaces, SDKs, and the like you should be aware of for Silverlight, WPF, *and* WinForms. Can you give us any more details about your UI designer and how it should function? Any specific information you're hoping to find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am also working on a similar project and we have used canvas as designer surface; as done in this CodeProject article -

> WPF Diagram Designer - Part 4
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx

One more project based on this can be found at codeplex-

> http://simulo.codeplex.com/

One more option is to use **.Net DesignSurface** that provides the design-time infrastructure at runtime as mentioned in this question -

[How to create an UI Designer utility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278488/how-to-create-an-ui-designer-utility/3279890#3279890)

Link there is not working, correct link to code project article is -

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DesignSurfaceManager_Ext.aspx

One more approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514176/building-visual-studio-like-application-need-inputs/2514363#2514363) is to use Visual Studio Shell(VS 2010), but I am not sure how useful it is.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you check out sharpdevelop http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/ It already has an open source implementation of gui designers (for winforms and wpf at least).

Comment: They also have a book about the subject which is now freeware.

Comment: looks like a great designer out of the box, but it looks like Winforms only!

Comment: for version 4 they have a xaml designer as well :)

Comment: But I guess its look and feel will be of WinForms only, its just that designer will support XAML too. Am I right?

Comment: the default look and feel of wpf applications is like winforms ... yes that is true. But if you do anything fancy like include themes into your app.xaml it will pick it up.