# Is possible to implement a toolbar and draw the control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, toolbar

I've got an idea which is trying to imitate VS.

In my project, I've created many views (user controls).

I want to display these views in a toolbar (like VS) and when I choose one of them, draw the selected view in another control (like a designer, I guess this can be a `grid` or `richtextbox`).

Is possible doing this? How much difficult would be? Does exists a demo in internet?

I question this because I'm not an expert in graphics with WPF.

Any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's pretty much possible and won't be too difficult to achieve, but that will depend on complexity of your controls; Look at this article series having similar implementation using `Canvas` -

WPF Diagram Designer - [Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4), [Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-3), [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23265/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-2), [Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)

One more project based on this article can be found at codeplex-

http://simulo.codeplex.com/

Also have look at this similar question for some other options -

[Creating a UI Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425626/creating-a-ui-designer/4427538#4427538)